# Find query result to List

Tags: mongodb, list, scala, casbah

I have got a database filled with documents like the following :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56zeffb2abcf7ff24b46"),
    "id_thing" : -1,
    "data" : {
        "info1" : 36.0709427,
        "date" : ISODate('2005-11-01T00:33:21.987+07:00'),
        "info2" : 24563.87148077
    }
}
```

My `find` method returns a `List` which I operate some operations over:

```
for (d <- result_of_find_method_here)
{
    val l_d = d("data")
}
```

But I would like to `l_d` a `List` which is currently not, and the `toList` method does not work.

How do I retrieve all the fields and their value of the `data` container as a list?

**EDIT:**

I have tried multiple methods, and none work because neither applies to `AnyRef` which is what I get when I iterate through the `l_d` with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Are you getting just plain json string from DB or it's wrapped into Play JsValue or something else?

Comment: It is plain json string.

Comment: Try to parse it into Play Json for example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884841/converting-json-string-to-a-json-object-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find method returns a list because there are more objects returned.
`l_d` is not a list, because `d['data']` is not a list is a key value store: a dictionary, json or map in Scala.  The question is how do you want to represent this data? 
Maybe you want to take out the values from the map as a list.

You can convert map to list using:   `l_d.toList`  or map values to list: `l_d.values.toList`

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to do? Do you know how?

Comment: try `l_d.toList`  and `l_d.values.toList`